# Clarify on Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> (1) Let $X\subseteq k^n$ be an algebraic variety, $k$ an algebraically closed field. Let $I(X)\subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the ideal of the polynomials vanishing on $X$; if it is proper, $X\neq\emptyset$.

> (2) Let $A$ be a finitely generated generated $K$-algebra, where $K$ is a field. If $A$ is a field, it is an algebraic extension of $K$.

First question: is (1) a rephrasing of (2) when $K=k$? I would say yes, because they both amount to say that the maximal ideals of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ are of the form $(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ for $a_1,\dots,a_n\in k$. However (1) doesn't say that for a general $K$, $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]/m$ (with $m$ a maximal ideal) is an algebraic extension.

Second question: in Atiyah-Macdonald (exercise 5.18) it is said that (2) is another version of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz (HN). But does that mean that (2) is an equivalent formulation of (HN) or just another similar result? I know that they are logically equivalent (being always true), but if there is a trivial way to traduce (2) into (HS) and viceversa, I can't see it. Thanks for any clarify

Comment: The Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, as I know it, states that the algebraic varieties in $k^n$ are in bijection with the radical ideals of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Comment: No, $(1)$ is not a rephrasing of $(2).$ There are no algebraic extensions to an algebraically closed field. If $A$ is a field, it corresponds to a maximal ideal od $K[x_1,\dots,x_n].$ If $K=k,$ these just corresponde to individual points in $k^n.$